# How to mount network drive and make it permanent using command line in mac?

Tags: macos, command-line, mount, network-shares, smb

I want to mount my network drive to my local folder in mac/osx.

I normally use **mount_smbfs** command but it won't mount automatically after restart or logout. For permanent option in mac :

`system preferences -> user&group -> add login item -> add my network drive`.

This way , the mount point will stay after restarting/logout. But how can i mount permanently using command line ?

Comment: That's a fair question I think. Unfortunately, the world's wealthiest corporation provides only scant and aged documentation. It's beyond aggravating. Anyway, ranting is probably not what you were looking for; I only commented here to suggest you look into automount. Unfortunately, again, there is no Apple documentation - [I used this blog post ](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/using-the-mac-os-x-automounter/) which didn't work at first, but I kept hacking at it & finally succeeded.